# Output multiple commands into columns

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script which runs various commands and outputs the result of each command into one column but I'm not able to get the output ot be displayed in colums.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get GBP Neighbour NAMES
NEIGHBOR=$(vtysh -c 'show ip bgp neighbors' | grep Incoming | awk '{print $7}')

# Get IPs of BGP neighbours
IP=$(vtysh -c 'show ip bgp summary' | awk '{print $1}' | head -n -2 | tail -n +6)

# Get Up/Down time
TIME=$(vtysh -c 'show ip bgp summary' | awk '{print $9}' | head -n -2 | tail -n +6)

# Get State/PfxRcd
STATE=$(vtysh -c 'show ip bgp summary' | awk '{print $10}' | head -n -2 | tail -n +6)
```

How can I get the output to be separated in columns such as:

```
NEIGHBOR | IP | TIME | STATE
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **`paste`** command:

```
paste -d'|' <(echo "$NEIGHBOR ") <(echo "$IP") <(echo "$TIME") <(echo "$STATE")
```

Comment: Wow! Great! Anyway to make the columns have the same width? to make it look cleaner and easier to read?

Comment: @KevinMaschke, try to pipe to `column` command, `paste ... | column -s'|' -t`

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest ! Adding `| column -s '|' -t` did the trick! I edited the question with the final result!