# Can you use the paste command with commands and not files?

Tags: bash, terminal, syntax, syntax-error

I'm using Git Bash.

I have a few log files. I want to get a nice list of date & time stamps. The file names start with a 4 digit date. Each line item in the files has the time.

I can run the commands separately to put the data into two files, and then mash up the files with the paste command. That works.

**So my question is this**: can I use commands instead of files within the paste command?

example:
instead of `paste file1 file2`, I want to use `paste (command1) (command2)`. Is this possible?

.

I tried grouping the commands like this :

```
paste (grep -F -e <string> <files> | cut -c1-4) (awk '/\-/ {print $1, $2}' <files>)
```

I got the error "syntax error near unexpected token grep"
So then I tried using command substitution:

```
paste $(grep -F -e <string> <files> | cut -c1-4) $(awk '/\-/ {print $1, $2}' <files>)
```

But unfortunately it didn't like this either. Anybody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to commenter, found the answer here:
[Output multiple commands into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285157/output-multiple-commands-into-columns)

Corrected code (that works) is:

```
paste <(grep -F -e <string> <files> | cut -c1-4) <(awk '/\-/ {print $1, $2}' <files>)
```

The difference being that the substituted commands are preceded by a '<' and not '$'.